# Using Python for web scraping: TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import json

serviceurl = "http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/geojson?"

while True:

address = "Farmingdale State University"
if len(address) < 1 : 
    break

url = serviceurl + urllib.parse.urlencode({'sensor':'false','address':address})

print ('Retrieving',url)


uh =urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = uh.read()
print ('Retrived',len(data),'characters')

try: (js) = json.loads(str(data))
except: (js) = None
if ('status' not in js) or (js['status'] != 'OK'):
    print ('==== Failure To Retrieve ====')
    print (data)
    continue

placeid = js["results"][0]['place_id']
print ("Place id",placeid)
```

> File "", line 23, in 
>       if ('status' not in js) or (js['status'] != 'OK'):
>
> TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Comment: If js is none, you can not iterate over it. 'status' in None is not possible

Answer (score 0):

If js is None then you will get this error. Try to check if js is True and only then go further into checking its content.

Right now when your code fails the try block and goes to except js will be set to None and then the if sentance is still checked.

Answer (score 0):

- [json.loads()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) - returns an object from a string representing a json object.

**Ex.**

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import json

serviceurl = "http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/geojson?"
address = "Farmingdale State University"
url = serviceurl + urllib.parse.urlencode({'sensor':'false','address':address})

while True:
    uh =urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    response = uh.read()
    data = json.loads(response)
    if 'status' in data and data['status'] != 'OK':
        continue
    #check place_id is exists in dictionary
    if 'results' in data and len(data['results']) > 0 and 'place_id' in data['results'][0]:
        print(data["results"][0]['place_id'])
        break
```

**O/P:**

```
ChIJScDUqFcq6IkRpvubNFOAVmw
```